# optimizing rc4 with cuda

Tags: optimization, cuda, implementation

I made some attempts to implement an efficient of rc4 cipher algorithm in cuda. I used shared memory to store the internal permutation state, taking care of the banked memory layout to time penalty with parallel thread accesses in the warp. I also tried to minimize the number of accesses exploiting the fact that read/write accesses with the 'i' index are contiguous and can be packed in 32-bits words. Last, I made use of constant memory to initialize the permutation state.

Despite these 'clever' tricks, i can expect to achieve only roughly 50% of throughput of the best reported implementations (see guapdf cracker for example), even taking into consideration that unblocked communication between host and gpu could be used to partially cover the computation. I can't figure why and I am looking for new improvement ideas or comments on bad assumptions i could have made.

Here is a toy implementation of my KSA (key setting) kernel with a key reduced to 4 bytes.

```cpp
__constant__ unsigned int c_init[256*32/4];

__global__ void rc4Block(unsigned int *d_out, unsigned int *d_in)
{
__shared__ unsigned int s_data[256*32/4];

int inOffset  = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
int in  = inOffset + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int key, u;

// initialization 
key = d_in[in];

for(int i=0; i<(256/4); i++) {  // read from constant memory
  s_data[i*32+threadIdx.x] = c_init[i*32+threadIdx.x];
}
// key mixing
unsigned char j = 0;
unsigned char k0 = key & 0xFF;
unsigned char k1 = (key >> 8) & 0xFF;
unsigned char k2 = (key >> 8) & 0xFF;
unsigned char k3 = (key >> 8) & 0xFF;

for(int i=0; i<256; i+=4) { // unrolled

  unsigned int u, sj, v;
  unsigned int si = s_data[(i/4)*32+threadIdx.x];
  unsigned int shiftj;

  u = si & 0xff;
  j = (j + k0 + u) & 0xFF;
  sj = s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x];
  shiftj = 8*(j%4);
  v = (sj >> shiftj) & 0xff;
  si = (si & 0xffffff00) | v;
  sj = (sj & ~(0xFFu << (8*(j%4)))) | (u << shiftj);
  s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x] = sj;

  u = (si >> 8) & 0xff;
  j = (j + k1 + u) & 0xFF;
  sj = s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x];
  shiftj = 8*(j%4);
  v = (sj >> shiftj) & 0xff;
  si = (si & 0xffff00ff) | (v<<8);
  sj = (sj & ~(0xFFu << (8*(j%4)))) | (u << shiftj);
  s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x] = sj;

  u = (si >> 16) & 0xff;
  j = (j + k2 +u) & 0xFF;
  sj = s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x];
  shiftj = 8*(j%4);
  v = (sj >> shiftj) & 0xff;
  si = (si & 0xff00ffff) | (v<<16);
  sj = (sj & ~(0xFFu << (8*(j%4)))) | (u << shiftj);
  s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x] = sj;

  u = (si >> 24) & 0xff;
  j = (j + k3 + u) & 0xFF;
  sj = s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x];
  shiftj = 8*(j%4);
  v = (sj >> shiftj) & 0xff;
  si = (si & 0xffffff) | (v<<24);
  sj = (sj & ~(0xFFu << (8*(j%4)))) | (u << shiftj);
  s_data[(j/4)*32+threadIdx.x] = sj;

  s_data[(i/4)*32+threadIdx.x] = si;
}
d_out[in] = s_data[threadIdx.x]; // unrelevant debug output 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code at least partially involves re-ordering bytes. If you are using a Fermi-class GPU, you could look into using the __byte_perm() intrinsic which maps to a hardware instruction on Fermi-class devices and allows one to re-order bytes more efficiently.

I assume when you compare to other implementations it is apples-to-apples, i.e. on the same type of GPU. This code looks entirely compute bound, so the throughput will largely depend on the integer-instruction throughput of the GPU, and the performance spectrum is wide.

Comment: Actually, i am working under older 'tesla' architecture so __byte_perm intrinsic (which seems good to know) cannot be used. My performance comparison is confirmed by benchmark timing i made with the same gpu card.

Comment: I looked up RC4 in Schneier and it is a byte-oriented algorithm using an SBOX made up from 256 one-byte entries. Your code appears to access the byte array a word at a time and extracts and inserts the bytes on the fly. These extractions/insertions would appear to take up a large portion of the overall execution time of this computationally bound task. Have you considered storing each SBOX element in a word, masking off to the least significant byte only as you write back each SBOX entry? In addition try using the input data via a char array rather than a word array.